# transition functions on vector bundles

Tags: vector-bundles

If we consider a vectorbundle $\pi:V\rightarrow M$ on a smooth manifold and two open subsets $U_1,U_2$ along with isomorphisms $h^{U_i}:\pi^{-1}(U_i)\rightarrow U_i\times \mathbb{R}^n$ s.t. $pr_1 \circ h^{U_i}=\pi$ and $h^{U_i}:\pi^{-1}(y)\rightarrow y\times\mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector space iso. My question is why the transition functions must be given by $h^{U_1}\circ (h^{U_2})^{-1}:U_1\cap U_2\times \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow U_1\cap U_2\times \mathbb{R}^n$,$h^{U_1}\circ (h^{U_2})^{-1}(x,v)=(x,A(x)v)$ . I think my problem is that i dont understand why $h^{U_i}|_{\pi{^-1}(U_1\cap U_2)}$ is still an isomorphism (is it?).

Comment: You matrix $A$ should depend on $x$. It’s actually map $A:U_1\cap U_2\to \operatorname{GL}(n)$. And that’s because, by definition, for each fixed $x$ you get a linear map $\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Of course, ill edit that. And i do understand why your second comment is true. But how does that show anything? It might be very trivial.

Comment: Then I don’t understand what your confusion might be. About your last question btw, the map $h^{U_i}|_{\pi^{-1}(U_1\cap U_2)}$ is still a homeomorphism onto its image as a restriction of a homeomorphism.

Comment: @T.P. i know that, but how de we know what that image is? Intuitively it should be $U_1\cap U_2\times \mathbb{R}^n$, but i can not see that popping out of the definition.